# How to find inverse of the function $f(x)=\sin(x)\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

My friend asked me to solve it, but I can't.

If $f(x)=\sin(x)\ln(x)$, what is $f^{-1}(x)$?

I have no idea how to find the solution. I try to find

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\ln(x)\cos(x)}$$

and try to solve it for $x$ by some replacing and other things, but I failed.

Can anyone help? Thanks to all.

Comment: When you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\sin`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Out of interest, why did you try to solve $df/dy$ for $x$? How were you intending on relating this to the inverse of $f(x)$?

Comment: what about $f(x)=e^{x}ln(x)$ it had one solution for evry y=a ?

Comment: user1729: in the past i solve question like my question by find the solve of dx/dy for x

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh Can you give a (quick) example? (Also, adding an "@" before my name sends me a message to say you've replied.)

Comment: @user1729  : i didnt rememper exactly what is the function i dealt with it but for example 
$y=xe^x$
$y'=e^x+y$
$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{e^x+y}$
now we have differintial equation 
the solution on the wolfram
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D1%2F%28e%5Ey%2Bx%29

Comment: i dont know if my way is correct or not 
if any one have different idea please tell me about it

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh I am still rather confused. I do not understand how finding the solutions to this differential equation helps you find the inverse. For example, $y=e^x$ is a solutions, but this is clearly not the function you are looking for!

Comment: @user1729:$$y=\exp^{x}$$ is a solution ?!

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $y=xe^x$ (oh...are solving the differential equation for $x$?).

Comment: @user1729
yes 
solve it for  

x=f(y)
and after solve it replace every y with x >>>$$f^{-1}(x)=y$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function fails the horizontal line test for one, very badly in fact. One to one states that for any $x$ and $y$ in the domain of the function, that $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$. that is to each point in the domain there exists a unique point in the range. Many functions can be made to be one to one $(1-1)$ by restricting the interval over which values are taken, for example the inverse trig functions and the square root function (any even root). We typically only take the positive square root because otherwise the function would have two answers and each x wouldn't have a unique y value (The so called vertical line test, which is why generally if functions fail the horizontal line test they don't typically have an inverse). If you graph this function it looks very much like a growing sinusoidal shape this cannot be restricted uniquely in a manner that makes an inverse definable.

Comment: you CAN ALWAYS invert the function numerically , try mathwolframalpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cinv%7Bsin%28x%29ln%28x%29%7D

Comment: thanks alot Jose Garcia i dont know that

Comment: I did once tell someone never to question wolframalpha..

Answer (score 5):

This function isn't one-to-one, so you can't inverse it.

Comment: can you explain what you mean (one-to-one) ?

Comment: Function is 1-1, when $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact it has an infinity of solutions for any real value of $y=f(x)$ as may be seen on this picture by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201=sin%28x%29*ln%28x%29) (nothing special happens near $0$ because of the equivalence to $x\ln(x)$) :

[image: solutions for 1]

You may find solutions numerically by iterations.

For example using Newton-Raphson applied to $\log(x)\sin(x)=y$ we get the first solution illustrated (at the left) in the case $y=1$ :
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\sin(x_n)\log(x_n)-y}{\cos(x_n)\log(x_n)+\sin(x_n)/x_n},\quad x_0=7$$
$$s_1\doteq 6.83056530451751861265\cdots$$

Comment: what about $f(x)=e^{x}ln(x)$

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: (sorry wrong equation previously) It has only one positive solution over $\mathbb{R}$ that you may find numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also note that generally $f(x)=g(x)\sin(x)$ cannot have an inverse if $g$ itself is not a periodic function. Let's look at your example of $\ln(x)\sin(x)$. (I'm using the sign $<$ to represent greater than or equal to) Since for $h(x)=\sin(x)$, $-1<\sin(x)<1$, then for $f(x)=\ln(x)\sin(x)$ we have $-\ln(x)<\sin(x)<\ln(x)$, and since $\ln(x)$ is increasing monotonically, the sinusoid will keep growing and it will not repeat.